# Get innerHTML and Place it to other InnerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

**UPDATED QUESTION**
I have two div(s) with `class` selector (as follow):

```
    <div class="harga celana-dalam">111</div>
    <div class="harga celana-dalam">222</div>
    <div class="harga celana-dalam">333</div>




    <div class="showHargaProd"><!--111 should be here-->/div>
    <div class="showHargaProd"><!--222 should be here-->/div>
    <div class="showHargaProd"><!--333 should be here-->/div>
```

Here's the custom js:

```
<script>
    function hargaProduk(){
         //global divHrg;
         var divHrg = document.querySelectorAll("[class='harga celana-dalam']");
         var divResult = document.querySelector("#showHargaProd");
                for (var i=0; i < divHrg.length; i++) {
                alert(divHrg[i].innerHTML);
                }
         }
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", hargaProduk);
</script>
```

What I want to try is: **copy all content** each of divs in `harga celana-dalam` into each of divs `showHargaProd`.

In my script above, I use `alert` fo see if it works. Using `alert`, it shows as I wished but I want each of them fill in each of `showHargaProd`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fill content of div with class with value of other class, you need to loop on the first class and fill the second.

```
<script>
    
    function hargaProduk() {

        let sources = document.querySelectorAll(".harga.celana-dalam");
        let dests = document.querySelectorAll(".showHargaProd");

        for (let i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {

            if (dests[i]) {
                dests[i].innerHTML = sources[i].innerHTML;
            }

        }
        
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", hargaProduk);
    
</script>
```

Comment: I have just updated my question to make it clear.

Comment: I still didn't get it when I wrote this: `[class='harga celana-dalam']` - I changed it like you said, and it works!

Comment: don't miss the ` if (dests[i]) { ` or ` if (divResult[i]){ ` because if u have more `celana-dalam` div than  `showHargaProd` div, you will have an error